# MySQL dump permission error

Tags: permissions, mysql, mysqldump

It seems strange but when doing

```
mysqldump -h host -u backup -p database | gzip > /tmp/test.gz
```

I get

```
Access denied for user 'backup'@'%' (using password: YES) when using LOCK TABLES
```

When connecting with

```
mysqldump -h host -u backup -p database
```

I get

```
mysql> lock tables booking read;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> unlock tables;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

so it seems the permission is there

```
show grants for current_user()
```

returns

```
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW ON *.* TO 'backup'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password here'
```

Is there any reason why it would not work rhough mysqldump

EDIT

Adding the reload permission I am able to do

`FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` so there is no permission issue

Comment: Quick question: Please login and run this `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` What is the output ?

Comment: no access currently, but i did before. It was `'backup'@'IP_CONNECTED_FROM'` and `'backup'@'%'`

Comment: Two questions: 1) All the tables are MyISAM ? 2) Do any of the tables have triggers ?

Comment: Yes and no. There is a trigger but its not needed ( in the backup)

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL Documentation on `mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables, SHOW VIEW for dumped views, **TRIGGER for dumped triggers**, and LOCK TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used. Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.

You said in [your comment](https://superuser.com/questions/872589/mysql-dump-permission-error#comment1161251_872589)

> There is a trigger but its not needed ( in the backup)

You either need the [TRIGGER privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger) or you can issue the mysqldump like this

```
mysqldump -h host -u backup -p database --skip-triggers | gzip > /tmp/test.gz
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: `GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW ON *.* ` are the permissions. the table is also not innodb

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Didnt change anything